# LIne Break before and after h1 tags

Tags: css

Hi i am new to CSS and i might be asking some school boy questions. I want to but a line break at the top of my post before and after my h1 tags. I might be trying to do this by the wrong method. Maybe i need some padding at the top but defiantly need a line break after each H1.

This is my css for posts

```
#kopa-post-content p,h1,h2,h3,h4 {text-align:left;margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px}
```

[Example of what i am trying to do.](https://buckspartyvenues.com.au/private-party-venues-sydney)

Any help will be gratefully received

Thanks

Danny

Comment: Your "example" doesn't really explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: h1 tags (and also all other h... tags and p tags) are block elements by default - they are always in a new line, and after them there will also be a line break.  Have you tried `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`?  These will create some vertical distance (but h1... tags have some margin-top and -bottom by efault, so the values have to be rather high for you to see an effect)

Answer (score 2):

A `h1` tag is a block element. It already has a "line break" before and after it. If you wish to increase the space above and below the element, use `margin`.

eg.

```
h1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

You should not use `<br>` for styling. You should use CSS, and you'll have a lot more control, too.

Answer (score 0):

One case where you don't and can't get a line break after `<h1>` is if you put the `<h1>` inside of a flex container (`display:flex`). In this case, it is treated as one of the flex items and arranged on the page as specified by `justify-content` and `align-items` or their defaults. Flex lines are lines of blocks, not lines of text.

Answer (score -1):

What you're talking about is referring to HTML not CSS. You can use the 
 tag in HTML to accomplish this.

```
<body>
  some text
  <br>
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
  <br>
  some more text
</body>
```